# Dynamically rendering an inline function in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, I am dynamically rendering some items in an object and tried to put an inline function that gets tied to a single item.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get(['player_info'], (data) => {
    console.log('search')
    console.log(data)
    // data = list of possible players 
    let player_arr = data.player_info
    for (let i = 0; i < player_arr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("card-wrapper").innerHTML +=
            `<div onclick="alert('clicked')" class="player_option">
                <center>
                    <div class="card-img-small">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img id=\"player_img\" src="${player_arr[i].profile_img}" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="player-name" class="price-small">
                        ${player_arr[i].name}
                    </div>`
    }
})
```

In the `div` wrapper, I added an `alert` function to check if it works, but nothing happens. I inspected the element, and it looked like this:

```
<div onclick="alert('clicked')" class="player_option">
                <center>
                    <div class="card-img-small">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img id="player_img" src="https://fmdataba.com/images/p/4348.png" class="img-responsive">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="player-name" class="price-small">
                        Paul Pogba
                    </div></div></div>
```

It seems like this is now allowed in Chrome Extension. What is a way to solve this without violating the security policy?

**EDIT - using addEventListener**

```
let player_arr = data.player_info
for (let i = 0; i < player_arr.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("card-wrapper").innerHTML +=
        `<div id="selected_player_${i}" class="player_option">
            <center>
                <div class="card-img-small">
                    <img id=\"player_img\" src="${player_arr[i].profile_img}" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </center>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div id="player-name" class="price-small">
                    ${player_arr[i].name}
                </div>`

    document.getElementById(`selected_player_${i}`).addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert(`${player_arr[i].name}`)
    })
}
```

Comment: You need to use `addEventListener()`

Comment: Could you plz elaborate?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: There is a way to bind `addEventListener()` to the entire `div`, but how can I make it different for each item that I am rendering?

Comment: @SLaks I edited my question. I tried something new with the `addEventListener()` but the alert doesn't work in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by making another for-loop for the `addEventListener()`.
If I put both HTML rendering and the `addEventListener` in a single for-loop as I did in my question, the `addEventListener` gets applied only to the last item.

```
const callname = (name) => {
    alert(name)
}

chrome.storage.sync.get(['player_info'], (data) => {
    console.log('search')
    console.log(data)
    // data = list of possible players
    let player_arr = data.player_info
    for (let i = 0; i < player_arr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("card-wrapper").innerHTML +=
            `<div id="selected_player_${i}" class="player_option">
                <center>
                    <div class="card-img-small">
                        <img id=\"player_img\" src="${player_arr[i].profile_img}" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </center>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="player-name" class="price-small">
                        ${player_arr[i].name}
                    </div>`
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < player_arr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById(`selected_player_${i}`).addEventListener("click", function() {
            callname(`${player_arr[i].name}`)
        })
    }
})
```